# Python Boto 3 version incompatible

Tags: python, amazon-s3, botocore

Need steps for downloading the correct versions botocore and s3transfer.
I did pip install awscli and got the following error because of which no module found shows up while running the .py script.
ERROR: boto3 1.10.50 has requirement botocore<1.14.0,>=1.13.50, but you'll have botocore 1.15.8 which is incompatible. ERROR: boto3 1.10.50 has requirement s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0, but you'll have s3transfer 0.3.3 which is incompatible

Comment: What operating system are you using? What command did you use when this error appeared? Did you use `sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade`? Or you using virtual environments?

Comment: Upgrade awscli at the same time: `pip install --upgrade boto3 awscli`

Comment: I am using Centos server. After upgrading I am still getting error, no module named: awscli. Should I specify the path to the modules anywhere?

Comment: Resolved thanks a lot!